# How to disable particular option dynamically in Angular Mat-Select

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-5

I have a list with an object has `name` and `id` properties:

```
[
  {
    "name": "open",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "inprogress",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "close",
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

And using MatSelect with *ngFor to iterate over an array and bind the current status with select using `[(ngModel)]`.

Expected output:

If the current status is `inprogress` then disable `open` option

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7etim?file=app/select-multiple-example.html)

Answer (score 25):

The example doesn't work properly because `selected` is bound with `[value]="topping.id"`, but the logic uses `selected.id` which doesn't exist except on startup because you are initializing `selected` with a topping object.

Also, the logic `[disabled]="topping.id < selected.id"` is possibly flawed because it also disables `inprogress` when `close` is selected  - you might want that - I'm not sure - but you only said you wanted to disable `open` when `inprogress` is selected.

Either use `[value]="topping"`:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [(ngModel)]="selected" [formControl]="toppings">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of list" [value]="topping" [disabled]="selected.id === '2' && topping.id === '1'">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Or change the logic and initialization of `selected`:

```
selected: any =  '2';

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [(ngModel)]="selected" [formControl]="toppings">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of list" [value]="topping.id" [disabled]="selected === '2' && topping.id === '1'">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Update for Angular v6/7 and later**

Use `[(value)]` instead of `[(ngModel)]`. Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and is removed in Angular v7.

Comment: should I use status name in If?

Comment: I am using the  `[(ngModel)]="obj.status"` which contains `name` and `code` in `status` object

Comment: So the status which come in `obj.status` is inprogress then `open` option will be only disable that my requirement

Comment: If your model uses the object `{name, code}` then follow the top example but replace `topping` with `status` (or `obj.status` I am not sure) and `id` with `code` I think.

Answer (score 3):

if user can select multiple options we dont really need ngModel as well, below is my solution to disable certain option on select of some different option in angular material mat-select.

```
//toppings is a form control name for mat-select
this.toppings.valueChanges.subscribe((selection) => { 

this.selected = '';

//includes because in case we are using multi selection we will receive selection as array

if(selection.includes('inprogress')) // if index instead of name use index value
this.selected = 'inprogress' // selected is globally defined variable
)}

checkUserSelection(topping){

if(this.selected === 'inprogress' && topping === 'open')"{
return true;
}
return false
}
```

----------------- Html Code ---------------------

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Toppings" 
[formControl]="toppings">

<mat-option *ngFor="let topping of list" 
<!-- Added null check for the topping field -->
[value]="topping?.id" 
[disabled]="checkUserSelection(topping)"
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this in HTML

```
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="algorithm">
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let algo of algos"
          [value]="algo.name"
          [disabled]="!algo.allow">
          {{ algo }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

and in ts

```
 algos = ['FIFO', 'LIFO'];
    somefunctionCall(){ // Map the Array
        const fifoAllowed = false;
        isAllowed = (algo) => algo === 'FIFO' ? fifoAllowed : true;
        this.algos = this.algos.map(a => ({ name: a, allow: isAllowed(a) })
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disabled option in mat-select by putting condition as below :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [(ngModel)]="selected" [formControl]="toppings">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of list" [value]="topping.id" [disabled]="topping.id < selected.id">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<br>
```

Comment: by defualt is the status is inprogress then open should be disbled

Comment: I have checked in stack Blitz and it is working fine.Where is creating issue?

Comment: This doesn't really work - the logic from the original code is wrong.

Comment: By default selected has value 2 (in progress) so open status (value = 1) is disabled because it is less than selected value.

Comment: If you paste this code into the stackblitz example, it does not work at all.

Comment: Please, always add a null check to your template fields so that your template won't break in any circumstance : topping?.id

Answer (score 0):

```
 regexStr = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$';
  @Input() isAlphaNumeric: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    return new RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  validateFields(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {

      this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
      event.preventDefault();

    }, 100)
  }
```