# Angular Material - Disable single dropdown option element based on the selection

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-select

I have an Angular Material dropdown menu, and I need to disable specific elements from that dropdown, based on which value is selected from another dropdown menu.

Here is the HTML for the two dropdowns:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select id="lineOfBusiness" formControlName="lineOfBusiness">
        <mat-option value="commercial">Commercial</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="residential" >Residential</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="industrial">Industrial</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select id="psv" formControlName="psv">
        <mat-option value="inclinometer">Inclinometer</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="heil" >Heil</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="radar">Radar</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="hydraulics">Hydraulics</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="coretex">Coretex</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

For example, the logic would look something like this:
If 'lineOfBusiness' = 'commercial', then in the 'psv' dropdown, 'radar' should be disabled.

In my form.component.ts file, I have this function, which is executing without error, but is not disabling the needed options.

```
disableOption(optionValue: string): void {
    console.log("Disabling " + optionValue);
    const psvControl = this.reactiveForm.get('psv');
    if (psvControl) {
        const option = psvControl.get(optionValue);
        if (option) {
            option.disable();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This similar question has a lot of answers you can check. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51551435/4962159

Comment: You can do that easily `<mat-option value="radar" [disabled]="myForm.get('lineOfBusiness').value === 'commercial'">Radar</mat-option>` in HTML or do you want make this in disable function only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key concept:

1. Get the MatSelect DOM element for `psv` control via the template reference variable.
2. Subscribe to the `lineOfBusiness` control's `valueChanges` to fire the `disableOption` method when the `lineOfBusiness` value is changed.
3. Set the mat-option disabled when the value "commercial" is selected for the `lineOfBusiness` control and vice versa.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';

private destroy$ = new Subject();

@ViewChild('psvSelect') psvSelect!: MatSelect;


ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.reactiveForm.controls.lineOfBusiness.valueChanges
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe((value) => {
      this.disableOption(value);
    });
}

disableOption(optionValue: string): void {
  console.log('Disabling ' + optionValue);

  if (optionValue === 'commercial')
    this.psvSelect.options.find((x) => x.value == 'radar')!.disabled = true;
  else
    this.psvSelect.options.find((x) => x.value == 'radar')!.disabled = false;
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

You need to declare the template reference variable `#psvSelect` as below:

```
<mat-select id="psv" formControlName="psv" #psvSelect>
    ...
</mat-select>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wjerzt?file=src%2Fmain.ts)